# addEventListener is not a function error ,when i use .split

Tags: javascript, php, html

i was trying do a table with auto fill to next input when i selected options from mysql ,i try run this code got error said addEventListener is not a function, i no good in Javascript ,what mistakes in my code ?

```
<select name="select" class="sku">    
       <option value="">Select Option</option>
        <?php
        $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sku_db'); 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cpu";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         echo "<option value='$row[Description]|$row[Sell_Price]'>$row[SKU]</option>";
        }?>
    </select>        
    <input type="text" class="desc"  ></input>
    <input type="text" class="desc1"  ></input>
```

```
<script>
    const spt = document.querySelector('.sku')+"";
    const aspt = spt.split("|");
    const select = aspt[0];
    const select1= aspt[1];
    const result = document.querySelector('.desc');
    const result1 = document.querySelector('.desc1');
        
    select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    result.value= select.value;
    result1.value= select1.value;
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `querySelector('.sku')+""` you are creating a string from a html element (you will get `[object HTMLSelectElement]` as a string). You then split the string and try to use it as if it were a dom object which it isnt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
const spt = document.querySelector('.sku');
const result = document.querySelector('.desc');
const result1 = document.querySelector('.desc1');

spt.addEventListener('change',function(e){

  let val = spt.value
  const aspt = val.split("|");
  const select = aspt[0];
  const select1= aspt[1];
  result.value= select;
  result1.value= select1;
});
```